# AngularJs "fog of war"

Tags: angularjs

A few months ago, I found an AngularsJs directive which creates a "fog of war".

When  applied to a DOM element, say a `<div>`, everything surroundiing it is greyed, with a specified degree of opacity.

I have searched and can't find it again. Does anyone know what it is, or something similar?

---

[Update] I am pretty sure that I saw it on http://ngmodules.org/, so I am now searching the site & wil  post here isf I find it.

---

[Update++] I think that I might have been misremembering http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-blurred-modal (take alook at the demo) However, that ought to be modifiable to apply it to other HTML elements. As I said, I want to select a nested `<div>` and to blur everything outside of it.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt see the bootstap modal window instead? Together with ui-bootstrap you can use it in an angular project

Comment: Do you have a URL? Is there a demo anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

to expand upon my comment:
It might be that you mean the bootstrap modal module as seen on [this w3 school page](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)
Bootstrap is a framework that provides an easier way to make responsive web sites, you can find it here: http://getbootstrap.com/
If you use angular I would advise bootstrap ui as wel since it doesn't require jquery and gives some added functionality made possible by angular.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks. I am using AngularJs Bootstrap-UI, so will try to figure out how to get it working

Comment: you're welcome, be sure to use the example on the angular-ui site as a guideline, things can get messy if you use the other examples and don't include jquery

Comment: Do you happen to have a URL for an example?

Comment: there is an example right here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal it is a bit advanced maybe but you can edit the plunkr to see what does what, thats how I learned anyway.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Not exactly what I want, though. I want to have the item on the page, not as a popup. I want to display a page and then programatically grey out its surrounds. I may be able to modify or borrow from that code, I suppose.